# How to do web presentations and slides using Polymer

Tags: polymer, presentation

There are a lot of [presentation frameworks](http://designzum.com/2014/02/07/best-javascript-html5-presentation-frameworks/) out there for html + js. What would be a good way to accomplish a similar presentation in polymer? Is there any polymer elements that would be candidates to present a new slide and friendly with polymers transitions? I'm doing more with polymer and prefer that to using the existing frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

The [core-pages](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-pages) and [core-animated-pages](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-animated-pages) can probably be used to make a deck.

[Here's an example that Addy Osmani put together](https://ele.io/addyosmani/polymer-slides)

There are also a few projects, [here](https://github.com/unbug/gdg14/) and [here](https://github.com/dmytroyarmak/polymer-ui-presentation).